# Mozilla Addon Development - Communicating between windows with different domains

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox-addon

I am trying to create an addon that will allow the user to query a dictionary site at will and view the definition of a chosen word. I have been struggling to find a way to communicate between the page-worker that I have to access the DOM of the dictionary site entry and the main page that the user is viewing. I know that the page-worker is able to scrape the definition from the DOM, as I am able to see the definition logged to the console. I am having issues getting postMessage and onMessage to cooperate. I am currently attempting to bridge the gap using iframes, though other approaches are welcome.

Here are some bits of my code...

index.js:

```
var getDefinition = "var def = document.getElementsByClassName('def-content');" +
                    "definition = def[0].textContent;" +
                    "word = document.getElementsByClassName('js-headword');" +
                    "word = word.textContent;" +
                    "self.port.emit('dialog', definition);" +
                    "var thiswin = document.getElementById('example').contentWindow;" +
                    "thiswin.postMessage(definition, '*');"

currPage = require("sdk/page-mod").PageMod({
    include: "*",
    contentScriptWhen: "ready",
    contentScriptFile: [
        data.url("jquery.js"),
        data.url("jquery-ui.min.js"),
        data.url("define.js"),
    ],
    onMessage: function(message){
        console.log("received message");
    },
    onAttach: function(worker){
        workers.push(worker);

        worker.on("message", function(definition){
            console.log("received message");
        });

        worker.port.on("dblclick", function(selected, thispage){
            newPage = require("sdk/page-worker").Page({
                contentURL: "http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/" + selected,
                contentScriptWhen: "ready",
                contentScriptFile: [
                    data.url("jquery.js"),
                    data.url("jquery-ui.min.js"),
                    data.url("iframe.js")
                ],
                contentScript: getDefinition,
                onMessage: function(message){
                    console.log("received message");
                }
            });
        });
    }
});
```

define.js:

```
function calldictionary(definition){
    console.log("here comes calldictionary");
    console.log(definition);
    $('div#definition').text(definition);
    $('#define').dialog("open");
}

function send(){
    var selected = getSelected();
    if (selected != ""){
        var mainwin = document.getElementById('example').contentWindow;
        $('iframe#example').attr('src', 'http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/' + selected);
        self.port.emit("dblclick", selected);
    }
}

function getSelected() {
    if (window.getSelection) {
        return window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection) {
        return document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return '';
}

$(window).dblclick(function() {
    send();
});

window.addEventListener("message", function(event){
    if (event.origin == "dictionary.reference.com"){
    console.log("received message");}
    }, false);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing up regular window messaging with [content script messaging](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/using_postMessage). Try this:

index.js

```
var getDefinition = "var def = document.getElementsByClassName('def-content');" +
                    "definition = def[0].textContent;" +
                    "word = document.getElementsByClassName('js-headword');" +
                    "word = word.textContent;" +
                    "self.port.emit('dialog', definition);";

currPage = require("sdk/page-mod").PageMod({
    include: "*",
    contentScriptWhen: "ready",
    contentScriptFile: [
        data.url("jquery.js"),
        data.url("jquery-ui.min.js"),
        data.url("define.js"),
    ],
    onMessage: function(message){
        console.log("received message");
    },
    onAttach: function(worker){
        workers.push(worker);

        worker.on("message", function(definition){
            console.log("received message");
        });

        worker.port.on("dblclick", function(selected, thispage){
            newPage = require("sdk/page-worker").Page({
                contentURL: "http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/" + selected,
                contentScriptWhen: "ready",
                contentScriptFile: [
                    data.url("jquery.js"),
                    data.url("jquery-ui.min.js"),
                    data.url("iframe.js")
                ],
                contentScript: getDefinition,
                onMessage: function(message){
                    worker.postMessage(message);
                }
            });
        });
    }
});
```

define.js:

```
function calldictionary(definition){
    console.log("here comes calldictionary");
    console.log(definition);
    $('div#definition').text(definition);
    $('#define').dialog("open");
}

function send(){
    var selected = getSelected();
    if (selected != ""){
        self.port.emit("dblclick", selected);
    }
}

function getSelected() {
    if (window.getSelection) {
        return window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection) {
        return document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return '';
}

$(window).dblclick(function() {
    send();
});

self.on("message", function(message){
    console.log("received message");}
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This allowed the windows to communicate with each other, though I am getting a warning regarding loading mixed active content. I had hoped that what I had set up would circumvent this, but apparently it does not. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That could be the iframe you're injecting in the 'send' function of your define.js file. You don't need that iframe, that's what the page workers are for. I edited the answer and removed that part.

Comment: I'm not sure which one, actually. I'm assuming it is where definition is passed from the dictionary window to the main window. It looks like the issue could be the result of transferring data from http to https, though. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Yes, I updated both files to reflect your suggestions.

Comment: If you already removed the iframe injection from your define.js then i'm pretty sure you are not generating that warning, since you're not making any HTTP request (at least not in the code you've shown), you're just passing data from your add-on script to your content script..it might be a problem with the page itself

Comment: Ah, I missed your comment edit earlier. I took out the iframe injection, but nothing seems to be happening now. I am still unable to inject raw HTML from the page-worker's window into the current window and none of my console.log()s are posting anything.